# .NET MAUI (.NET 8) minimum android-ios version?

Tags: c#, android, ios, maui

I researched on the internet, some sources say that .NET 8 supports minimum Android 6 version, and some sources say that .NET 8 supports minimum Android 10 version?

Could you please give me clear information? Minimum android-ios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are `.NET MAUI 8` Supported OS versions for **Android** and **iOS**:

**Android:**

| OS | Version | Architectures |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Android | API 21+ | x64, Arm32, Arm64 |

**iOS:**

| OS | Version | Architectures |
| --- | --- | --- |
| iOS | 11.0+ | Arm64 |
| iOS Simulator | 11.0+ | x64, Arm64 |

For more details, you can refer to [Supported platforms for .NET MAUI apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/supported-platforms?view=net-maui-8.0).